# Can move only the last object placed in Scene

Tags: scenekit, arkit

Hy! I can move only the last virtual object placed in scene. When i add another object, the previous object added remains static and i cannot do any action on it. Can you give me please give me a solution to move, scale, rotate what object i want when I touch it?

Comment: You need to post some code so we can help...

Comment: [Here](https://files.fm/u/2np9qmxd)  is the compressed project I work on to learn Augumented Reality :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you haven't posted any code, its hard to provide an exact answer.

However, in order to keep track of the current `SCNNode` you wish to use, when you load a model etc you could store it as a variable e.g:

```
var currentNode: SCNNode!
```

You could also use the `name` property of the node when you are loading your model to keep a more specific reference to it.

Here is an example of doing this:

```
/// Example Of Loading An SCNScene & Setting It As The Current Node
func loadModel(){

        let modelPath = "Character.scn"

        //1. Get The Reference To Our SCNScene & Get The Model Root Node
        guard let model = SCNScene(named: modelPath),
            let modelObject = model.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Root", recursively: false) else { return }

        //2. Scale It
        modelObject.scale = SCNVector3(0.4, 0.4, 0.4)

        //3. Add It To The Scene & Position It 1.5m Away From The Camera
        augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelObject)
        modelObject.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)

        //4. Set It As The Current Node & Assign A Name
        currentNode = modelObject
        currentNode.name = "Character"

 }
```

You can also make use of an `SCNHitTest` which:

> Looks for SCNGeometry objects along the ray you specify. For each
>   intersection between the ray and and a geometry, SceneKit creates a
>   hit-test result to provide information about both the SCNNode object
>   containing the geometry and the location of the intersection on the
>   geometry’s surface.

This can be used to differentiate between which node(s) have been hit e.g:

```
/// Detects A Tap On An SCNNode
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer
@objc func detectTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Touch Point
    let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2a. Perform An SCNHitTest To Detect If An SCNNode Has Been Touched
    guard let nodeHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, options: nil).first else { return }

    if nodeHitTest.node == currentNode{
        print("The Current Node Has Been Touched")
    }

    //Or To See Which Node Has Been Touched
    if nodeHitTest.node.name == "The Model"{
        print("The Model Has Been Touched")
    }
}
```

Another way you can handle this is to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to your view, and enable interaction based on the result e.g. setting the currentNode that way e.g:

```
/// Detects A Tap On An SCNNode & Sets It As The Current Node
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer
@objc func detectTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Touch Point
    let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2a. Perform An SCNHitTest To Detect If An SCNNode Has Been Touched
    guard let nodeHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, options: nil).first else { return }

    //2b. Set It As The Current Node
    currentNode = nodeHitTest.node
}
```

Then you can apply logic to ensure that only the `currentNode` moves etc:

```
/// Moves An SCNNode
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer
@objc func moveNode(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    //1. Get The Current Touch Point
    let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2. If The Gesture State Has Begun Perform A Hit Test To Get The SCNNode At The Touch Location
    if gesture.state == .began{

        //2a. Perform An SCNHitTest To Detect If An SCNNode Has Been Touched
        guard let nodeHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, options: nil).first else { return }

        //2b. Get The SCNNode Result
        if nodeHitTest.node == currentNode{

            //3a. If The Gesture State Has Changed Then Perform An ARSCNHitTest To Detect Any Existing Planes
            if gesture.state == .changed{

                //3b. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
                guard let hitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }

                //3c. Convert To World Coordinates
                let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform

                //3d. Set The New Position
                let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)

                //3e. Apply To The Node
                currentNode.simdPosition = float3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This should be more than enough to point you in the right direction...